# finding the recursive function for given code

Tags: recursive-algorithms

[image]

Hey guys, can you give me some guidelines on how to get through questions like this, and help get the closed formula T(n) of the function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This sort of question is really not appropriate here; you're asking for a tutorial on "big-O analysis of algorithms," a topic that occupies full chapters in many books (and about 5 or 6 lectures in at least one intro CS course that I teach). Any (good) answer to the question would be pages long. Also, in general including images in your question is a bad idea -- it makes the question not searchable later. As a first step to addressing the problem you've got, I'd suggest searching the internet for "Introduction to runtime analysis" or "Intro to big-O".

Comment: ok, got it. sorry and thanks!